# Weird Object error on 2nd loop of while

Tags: excel, vba

UPDATE: I'm an idiot

SO this gives me the classic Object required error and i'm not 100% sure why.  It works on the first loop then errors on the second... meh?

```
Private Sub Email_Click()
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim address As String
    Dim startCell
    Dim currentCell
    counter = 0
    startCell = "B5"
    Set currentCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Follow Up").Range(startCell) '.Offset(counter, 0).Value


While currentCell > 0


    address = currentCell.Offset(counter, 2).Value
    If (currentCell.Offset(counter, 2) > 0) Then
        CreateMail (address)
        <s>counter = counter + 1</s>
        currentCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Follow Up").Range(startCell).Offset(counter, 0)
    Else

    End If
**counter = counter + 1**
  Wend
 counter = 0
End Sub
```

this is what the sheet looks like right now.  it's all test.

```
Date    Member ID   Name    Email       Notes
 1948828    bobby   bob@bob.com     awsda
 2166295    jim         
 2274434    james   Me@you.com
```

EDIT* adding CreateMail code

```
Private Sub CreateMail(address As String)
    Dim myolapp As Object
    Dim myitem As Object

    Set myolapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    myolapp.Session.Logon

    Set myitem = myolapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B11").Value + "NMFU.oft")
    myitem.Body = "Hey test" & myitem.Body
    myitem.Display 'or send
    myitem.to = address

End Sub
```

Comment: **1.** You are not exiting the loop, e.g. the possible exit is in a condition. **2.** `CreateMail (address)` is probably doing something related to the error.

Comment: `currentCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Follow Up").Range(startCell).Offset(counter, 0)` needs to be `Set currentCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Follow Up").Range(startCell).Offset(counter, 0)`. However, your code is far from being optimal

Comment: Also, `Dim currentCell As Range`.

Comment: Nice it works but then I think gets stuck in the loop so my logic is probably wrong. The error once it crashes is (and i can only see it briefly before it closes) "Method _Defaul' of object 'Range' Failed..  Imma poke it for a hot minute and see if i can figure it out.  Of course i'll always take help (hence being on this site. :) )

Comment: thanks @ShaiRado rado but I never quite get it yet.  I have currentCell as Range and even use the set keyword for it. Thus it should be an object, right? Well if i change the while to 'While currentCell Is Not Empty' but says it requires an object.

Comment: @Xellinus if you tell us what you are trying to achieve, perhaps we can offer an easier code, and a more reliable one

Comment: I edited to update with the other snip of code.  I'm just parsing down a list of emails (all lines have a Member ID and name but not all have email and notes) and sending a templated email for each email address.  There will be more customization later (adding in names to the email etc etc) but for now i'm just trying to get the loop for emailing everyone down.

Comment: I've thought about parsing everything into a nested array but felt that was a little unnecessary.  The looping, which should be super simple, is vexing me.  I'm used to more complex languages so i feel a fool here @ShaiRado

Comment: Which line is causing the crash? Step through it or use some logging. And if cuurentCell really is a Range, technically it can't be > 0. VBA is forgiving, but your lack of data typing can be setting traps, here...

Comment: well the >0 is just an attempt to say "if that cell is empty stop"  but `While currentCell Is Not Empty` doesn't work as it claims currentCell is not an object which i thought it was.